# How to push Docker images to AWS ECR within GoCD Pipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, go-cd

I already have existing GoCD Pipelines set up which push to my own Docker Registry. This all works fine, however I want to replace my Docker Registry with Amazon's ECR.

When communicating with ECR via AWS CLI it seems you have to pre-authenticate prior to pushing/pulling images which makes the process more clunky: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/Registries.html#registry_auth

I wanted to know if anyone had a more elegant solution to using Go  Pipelines to integrate with AWS ECR?

Comment: I think you just go about executing `aws ecr login` and make the push afterwards.

Comment: I was hoping somebody may have found a more elegant solution than this, as the ecr login has a 12 hours expiry it seems unnecessary to have to renew this for every single interaction.